# How to change the order of content types

Tags: i18n-l10n

How would one go about changing the order of the content types list on a multilingual site or non-english site?

For example, by adding a content type named Émission (with accentuated É), we see the following list on admin/structure/types page:

- Article
- Page
- Émission

Same goes when translating a content type name (E.g.: Show => Émission) and changing language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`node_type_get_names()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_names/7) calls the utility function [`_node_types_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/_node_types_build/7).  If you look at the source, there is a call to [`asort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) at the bottom.

If you read the documentation for `asort()`, you will see that it isn't called with it's second parameter, [`$sort_flags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#refsect1-function.sort-parameters).  This means that it will be called with the default, which is "normal" rules.  In this case, I am prety sure normal rules means ordering based on the value of the code point, which places the English alphabet first, then "specials".

To take your characters with diacriticals into account, you would have have a proper locale defined, and then call `asort()` with the `SORT_LOCALE_STRING` option.  For example,

```
$types = array('Émission', 'Page', 'Article');
print_r($types);

sort($types);
print_r($types);

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr');
sort($types, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
print_r($types);
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => Émission
    [1] => Page
    [2] => Article
)
Array
(
    [0] => Article
    [1] => Page
    [2] => Émission
)
Array
(
    [0] => Article
    [1] => Émission
    [2] => Page
)
```

That explains why the ordering isn't what you expect.  A quick look through the Drupal source only reveals a single call to [`setlocale(LC_ALL, 'C');`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) (it's in the bootstrap).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231620/what-does-set-localelc-ctype-c-actually-do for what this does.

All of this means that without doing a `hook_menu_alter()` on the 'admin/structure/types' to change the page callback to be your own, or to `hook_pager_alter()` the render array for the page, you can't change the ordering.

As a stupid American :) who doesn't really understand all of the implications of localization and internationalization, I cann't comment whether the Drupal behavior is by-design or is a bug.

Comment: And thanks to @AnilSagar whose answer prompted me to dig into this and so some experiments.